# Standalone ASIO library has different behaviour on OSX and Linux systems after write error

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, boost-asio, asio

I have noticed that on OSX asio::async_write function always calls handler callback. But on linux (Ubuntu 18.04) after async_write operation completes with error 3 times (Connection reset by peer or Broken pipe) handler callback is not called anymore after next call to async_write.

Please take a look at the code example:

```
    asio::io_service ioService;

    asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(ioService);

    // ---- Initialize server -----
    auto acceptor = make_unique<asio::ip::tcp::acceptor>(ioService,
        resolver.resolve(asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query(asio::ip::tcp::v4(), "localhost", "12345"))->endpoint());;
    asio::ip::tcp::socket serverSocket(ioService);
    std::promise<void> connectedPromise;
    std::promise<void> disconnectedPromise;
    std::vector<uint8_t> readBuffer(1);
    acceptor->async_accept(serverSocket, [&](asio::error_code errorCode) {
        std::cout << "Socket accepted!" << std::endl;
        connectedPromise.set_value();
        serverSocket.async_read_some(asio::buffer(readBuffer), [&](asio::error_code errorCode, std::size_t length) {
            if (errorCode) {
                std::cout << "Read error: " << errorCode.message() << std::endl;
                disconnectedPromise.set_value();
            }
        });
    });

    // ----- Initialize client --------
    asio::ip::tcp::socket clientSocket(ioService);
    asio::connect(clientSocket, resolver.resolve({asio::ip::tcp::v4(), "localhost", "12345"}));

    // ----- Start io service loop
    std::thread mainLoop([&]() {
        ioService.run();
    });

    connectedPromise.get_future().get(); // Wait until connected

    // ----- Perform 10 async_write operations with 100 ms delay --------

    std::promise<void> done;
    std::atomic<int> writesCount{0};
    std::vector<uint8_t> writeBuffer(1);

    std::function<void (const asio::error_code&, std::size_t)> writeHandler = [&](const asio::error_code& errorCode, std::size_t) -> void {
        if (errorCode) {
            std::cout << errorCode.message() << std::endl;
        }
        if (++writesCount < 10) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
            asio::async_write(serverSocket, asio::buffer(writeBuffer), writeHandler);
        } else {
            done.set_value();
        }
    };

    asio::async_write(serverSocket, asio::buffer(writeBuffer), writeHandler);

    clientSocket.close(); // Perform disconnect from client side
    disconnectedPromise.get_future().get(); // Wait until disconnected

    std::cout << "Waiting for all operations complete" << std::endl;
    done.get_future().get(); // Wait until all 10 async_write operations complete
    std::cout << "All operations complete" << std::endl;

    ioService.stop();
    mainLoop.join();
```

Output on OSX:

```
Socket accepted!
Broken pipe
Read error: Connection reset by peer
Broken pipe
Waiting for all operations complete
Broken pipe
Broken pipe
Broken pipe
Broken pipe
Broken pipe
Broken pipe
Broken pipe
All operations complete
```

Output on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
Socket accepted!
Read error: End of file
Connection reset by peer
Waiting for all operations complete
Broken pipe
Broken pipe
```

Linux version hangs on `done.get_future().get()` line because async_write completion handler is not called after several Broken pipe errors. I expect that any async_write operation should lead to handler call regardless of the socket status as in OSX version.
Is it a bug in linux version?

Asio version:  1.14.0 (standalone)

Comment: I didn't find the solution. Finally I just handle the error code in write handler and close socket and stop sending data in case of error.

Answer (score 0):

You have condition race on `ioService.run()`.

The [reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context/run/overload1.html) states:

> The run() function blocks until **all work has finished** and **there are no**
>   **more handlers to be dispatched**.

You have to call `reset()` on `ioService` if service stopped working due to lack of handlers.

> A normal exit from the run() function implies that the io_context
>   object is stopped (the stopped() function returns true). Subsequent
>   calls to run(), run_one(), poll() or poll_one() will return
>   immediately unless there is a prior call to restart().

The diagram below shows where condition race occurs:

```
main thread                                   background thread

[1] async_accept

[2] ioService.run()
                                              [3] handler for async_accept is called 
                                                  connectedPromise.set_value();
                                              [4] async_read_some 

[5] connectedPromise.get_future().get();

---> now here is a problem 
                   What [6.a] or [6.b] will be called as first?

[6.a] async_write which can push 
      a new handler to be processed      
                                       or 
                                          [6.b] handler for async_read_some 
                                               if this handler was called,
                                               ioService::run() ends, and you have to call reset on 
                                               it to accept new incoming handlers
```

(In square brackets are all steps in time order)

In your case 6.b happens. Handler for `async_read_some` is called as first, and in this handler you don't initiate any new handlers. As a result, `ioService::run()` stops, and handler for `async_write` will not be invoked.

Try to use [executor_work_guard](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/executor_work_guard.html) to prevent `ioService::run()` from stopping when there is no handlers to be dispatched.

Comment: Actually there is no race condition. Because nobody sends data to the socket. That's why handler for async_read_some can only be called with error (End of file) after main thread calls `clientSocket.close()`. When it happens async_write is already called.
I have just in case added `executor_work_guard` and got the same result.